# Initializing CanvasBitmap UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, directx, directx-11, win2d

I'm trying to convert `SoftwareBitmap` into `CanvasBitmap` (on UWP).
But when I used `BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8` && `BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied`, I got an error like `unsupported pixel format or alpha mode`.

I decided to try all possible formats with following code:

```cs
if (softwareBitmap != null)
{
    var wasSuccess = false;
    foreach (var bitmapAlphaMode in new[] {BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, 
                                           BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore})
    {
        foreach (var bitmapPixelFormat in new[] { 
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8, BitmapPixelFormat.Gray16, 
            BitmapPixelFormat.Yuy2, BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16, 
            BitmapPixelFormat.Nv12, BitmapPixelFormat.P010, BitmapPixelFormat.Unknown
        })
        {
            if (wasSuccess)
            {
                break;
            }
            try
            {
                SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, bitmapPixelFormat, bitmapAlphaMode);
                var bitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(
                    _canvasDevice, 
                    softwareBitmap
                );
                wasSuccess = bitmap != null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But after all possible attempt's, `wasSuccess` is `false`. (`_canvasDevice` was initialized successfully, that's not the problem).

How can it be?

Comment: A bit map has an ASCII header.  Read the string header to check type of image.  Your graphic driver may not support the format or you need to update the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But after all possible attempt's, wasSuccess is false. (_canvasDevice was initialized successfully, that's not the problem).

Not all BitmapPixelFormats are supported by CanvasBitmap, please refer to [`CreateFromSoftwareBitmap`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI3/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_CreateFromSoftwareBitmap.htm) document remarks part , You could find `BitmapPixelFormat.Unknown` `BitmapPixelFormat.Gray16` `BitmapPixelFormat.Nv12` `BitmapPixelFormat.Yuy2` is not supported.

And not all AlphaModes  are available for `CanvasBitmap`, please refer to this [document](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI3/html/PixelFormats.htm). You will find `CanvasBitmap` compatible with Premultiplied, Ignore alpha mode. Only `A8UIntNormalized` `A8UIntNormalized` support `Straight` alpha mode.

By the way, there is an error in `SoftwareBitmap.Convert` method in above code segment. You should assign the return value to  softwareBitmap like following, or it will never update softwareBitmap property.

```
softwareBitmap =  SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, bitmapPixelFormat, bitmapAlphaMode);
```